# Can the same linq expression be translated to different SQL statement depending on the DB?

Tags: c#, linq, informix, entity-framework-6.2

I have been working on a ASP.NET MVC project where we use Informix DB and Entity Framework for our queries. The thing is that depending on which DB the application is connected to, some LINQ queries are translated to different SQL queries.

That is I connect to DB 1 and the query is working and is translated more or less like this:

```
Opened connection asynchronously at 26/9/2019 12:48:27 +03:00
SELECT SKIP 0 FIRST 25 
...
FROM ( SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT 
        ...
        FROM   LATERAL (SELECT 
            ... ) AS Project1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  LATERAL (SELECT  FIRST 1 Project2.C1 AS C1
            FROM  LATERAL ( SELECT 
                ...
            )  AS Project2
            ORDER BY ... ASC ) AS Limit1 ON 1 = 1 
    )  AS Project3
)  AS Project3
ORDER BY ...
-- p__linq__0: 'M' (Type = String, Size = 1)
-- p__linq__1: '1/1/2018 00:00:00' (Type = DateTime, Size = 16)
-- p__linq__2: '1/1/2019 00:00:00' (Type = DateTime, Size = 16)
-- Executing asynchronously at 26/9/2019 12:48:27 +03:00
```

using the same exact code I restart the application and connect to DB 2 and the same LINQ expression is translated to the following SQL query that fails:

```
Opened connection asynchronously at 26/9/2019 12:41:00 +03:00
SELECT SKIP 0 FIRST 25 
...
FROM ( SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT 
        ...
        FROM   (SELECT 
            ... ) AS Project1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT  FIRST 1 Project2.C1 AS C1
            FROM ( SELECT 
                ...
            )  AS Project2
            ORDER BY ... ASC ) AS Limit1 ON 1 = 1 
    )  AS Project3
)  AS Project3
ORDER BY ...
-- p__linq__0: 'M' (Type = String, Size = 1)
-- p__linq__1: '1/1/2018 00:00:00' (Type = DateTime, Size = 16)
-- p__linq__2: '1/1/2019 00:00:00' (Type = DateTime, Size = 16)
-- Executing asynchronously at 26/9/2019 12:41:00 +03:00
-- Failed in 403 ms with error: ERROR [IX000] [IBM][IDS/UNIX64] Column (...) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined).
```

You can notice that the second query is missing the **LATERAL** keyword. Is it possible that just the DB connected, affects the LINQ translation to SQL?

edit to answer questions:
@Fildor the DBs are not the exact same version:

```
- DB1 is IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC6WE
- DB2 is IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC10
```

@Corak as far as I know the DB schema regarding the missing column is the same in both DBs. Since I cannot be 100% sure though, could that be the case? All columns are there though, if there is any difference it will be in foreign keys i.e. The thing is that the two queries are exactly the same with the only difference being the LATERAL keyword. [This](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0254.htm) is the documentation of IBM regarding LATERAL keyword. It makes sense to me that without it the "missing" column cannot be found in the subquery.

Comment: Both DBs are the same InformixDB version? Same setup, same tables ... ? Only different in actual data content?

Comment: "ERROR [IX000] [IBM][IDS/UNIX64] Column (...) not found" -- apparently the two DBs are different. Have you checked for differences regarding the mentioned columns?

Comment: EF is free to interpret the LINQ expression (which is a good thing, because at execution time there is more information to possibly make a more optimized query) so it's not necessary that the same LINQ always results in the same SQL. Side note: even the same SQL statement can lead to different execution plans on the server, which again is usually a good thing, because again the server has usually even more information (statistics) about the current state of the DB to make judgement calls. It can also be terribly terribly wrong, though...

Comment: you are not making much sense... if its the same linq then it will produce the same same, regardless of the link, otherwise you would get an error, inlcude the linq.

Comment: what is different between the two databases?

Comment: its like its telling you what is wrong `Column (...) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined).` but you ignoring it?

Comment: @Seabizkit I cannot include the linq since it would make no sense with the deductions and it is a big one dynamically constructed. You may find some answers in your questions in my edit as well.

Comment: you should include the version of EF and the version of Informix db provider used. are the connections made within the same project aka the same versions of Ef and Informix db provider are used.